# Open Office Spreadsheet (Calc) - Concatenate text cells with delimiters

Tags: openoffice.org, spreadsheet, concatenation

I am using Open Office's spreadsheet program and am trying to concatenate several text cells together with delimeters.  For example, suppose I have the cells below:

```
+--------+
| cell 1 |
+--------+
| cell 2 |
+--------+
| cell 3 |
+--------+
| cell 4 |
+--------+
| cell 5 |
+--------+
```

I would like to concatenate them with delimiters so that the result is in one cell like this one:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| (cell 1),(cell 2),(cell 3),(cell 4),(cell 5) |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

My first thought was to try and make a macro or something, but I don't think open office supports those.  Any ideas?

Comment: This will get a better response on Super User. You don't need to repost it there as the question will be moved automatically.

Comment: Oh, wow, I didn't even know super user existed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, after a lot more searching and experimenting, I found you can make your own functions in calc.  This is a function I made that does what I want:

```
Function STRCONCAT(range)
    Dim Row, Col As Integer
    Dim Result As String
    Dim Temp As String

    Result = ""
    Temp = ""

    If NOT IsMissing(range) Then
        If NOT IsArray(range) Then
            Result = "(" & range & ")"
        Else
            For Row = LBound(range, 1) To UBound(range, 1)
                For Col = LBound(range, 2) To UBound(range, 2)
                    Temp = range(Row, Col)
                    Temp = Trim(Temp)
                    If range(Row, Col) <> 0 AND Len(Temp) <> 0 Then
                        If(NOT (Row = 1 AND Col = 1)) Then Result = Result & ", "
                        Result = Result & "(" & range(Row, Col) & ") "
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    End If

    STRCONCAT = Result
End Function
```

Answer (score 30):

Thanks a lot Markus for finding a solution to this.

Here are some slightly more detailed instructions for the benefit of OpenOffice Basic newbies like myself.  This applies to version 3.1:

Tools -> Macros -> Organize Macros -> OpenOffice.org Basic...

Now select from the explorer tree where you want your function live,
e.g. it can be in your own macro library (My Macros / Standard) or
stored directly in the current spreadsheet.

Now enter a new Macro name and click New to open the OO.org Basic IDE.  You'll see a REM
statement and some stub Sub definitions.  Delete all that and replace
it with:

```
Function STRJOIN(range, Optional delimiter As String, Optional before As String, Optional after As String)
    Dim row, col As Integer
    Dim result, cell As String

    result = ""

    If IsMissing(delimiter) Then
        delimiter = ","
    End If
    If IsMissing(before) Then
        before = ""
    End If
    If IsMissing(after) Then
        after = ""
    End If

    If NOT IsMissing(range) Then
        If NOT IsArray(range) Then
            result = before & range & after
        Else
            For row = LBound(range, 1) To UBound(range, 1)
                For col = LBound(range, 2) To UBound(range, 2)
                    cell = range(row, col)
                    If cell <> 0 AND Len(Trim(cell)) <> 0 Then
                        If result <> "" Then
                            result = result & delimiter
                        End If
                        result = result & before & range(row, col) & after
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    End If

    STRJOIN = result
End Function
```

The above code has some slight improvements from Markus' original:

- Doesn't start with a delimiter when the first cell in the range is empty.
- Allows optional choice of the delimiter (defaults to ","), and the
  strings which go before and after each non-blank entry in the range
  (default to "").
- I renamed it STRJOIN since "join" is the typical name of this
  function in several popular languages, such as Perl, Python, and Ruby.
- Variables all lowercase

Now save the macro, go to the cell where you want the join to appear,
and type:

```
  =STRJOIN(C3:C50)
```

replacing C3:C50 with the range of strings you want to join.

To customise the delimiter, instead use something like:

```
  =STRJOIN(C3:C50; " / ")
```

If you wanted to join a bunch of email addresses, you could use:

```
  =STRJOIN(C3:C50; ", "; "<"; ">")
```

and the result would be something like

```
<foo@bar.com>, <baz@qux.org>, <another@email.address>, <and@so.on>
```

Comment: Wow this is horrible. It should be a standard open office function.

Answer (score 1):

Ever so often I'd enjoy the ease and quickness of replace & calculation Options as well as in general the quick handling & modifying Options, when once again sitting in front of a dumped-file-lists or whatsoever.

I never understood why they didn't include such an essential function right from the start, really.

It's based on Adam's script, but with the extension to swap `CONCAT` from horizontal to vertical, while still keeping the delimiters in order.

```
Function CONCAT2D(Optional range,   Optional delx As String, Optional dely As String, _
                                    Optional xcell As String, Optional cellx As String, _
                                    Optional swop As Integer)
    Dim xy(1), xyi(1), s(1) As Integer
    Dim out, cell, del, dxy(1) As String

    'ReDim range(2, 1)           'Gen.RandomMatrix 4 Debugging
    'For i = LBound(range, 1) To UBound(range, 1)
    '   For j = LBound(range, 2) To UBound(range, 2)
    '       Randomize
    '       range(i,j) = Int((100 * Rnd) )
    '   Next
    'Next

    out  = ""
    If IsMissing(delx)  Then : delx  = ","      : End If
    If IsMissing(dely)  Then : dely  = delx()   : End If
    If IsMissing(xcell) Then : xcell = ""       : End If
    If IsMissing(cellx) Then : cellx = xcell()  : End If
    If IsMissing(swop)  Then : swop  = 0        : End If
    dxy(0) = delx() : dxy(1) = dely()
    xyi(0) = 1      : xyi(1) = 2
    If swop = 0     Then :  s(0) = 0 : s(1) = 1
                    Else    s(0) = 1 : s(1) = 0 : End If

    If NOT IsMissing(range) Then
        If   NOT IsArray(range) _
        Then :  out = xcell & range & cellx
        Else    del = delx
                For xy(s(0)) = LBound(range, xyi(s(0))) To UBound(range, xyi(s(0))
                For xy(s(1)) = LBound(range, xyi(s(1))) To UBound(range, xyi(s(1))
                    cell = range(xy(0), xy(1))
                    If cell <> 0 AND Len(Trim(cell)) <> 0 _
                    Then :  If out <> "" Then : out = out & del : End If
                            out = out & xcell & cell & cellx
                            del = dxy(s(0))
                    End If
                Next :      del = dxy(s(1))
                Next
        End If
    Else        out = "ERR"
    End If

    CONCAT2D = out
End Function
```