# libreoffice calc - varargs in macros

Tags: macros, libreoffice, openoffice.org, basic, libreoffice-calc

I understand Excel has a `TEXTJOIN`function which allows one to display multiple values as a tuple.

I also understand Libre Office does - for whatever reason - not have them.

How do I write an auxiliary macro `vec` that produces the desired tuple representation for me?

E.g. `=vec(A1)` should produce `="("&A1&")"`,

`=vec(A1:A3)` should produce `="("&A1&","&A2&","&A3&")"`,

`=vec(A1,X5:X99,Z3)` should result in `="("&A1&","&"X5"&","&X6&...&x99&","&Z3&")"`

etc, etc.

Easy enough a macro to implement in, say, bash, but I would like to just define it once then use it in calc, not constantly copy from console to spreadsheet.

How do I implement this in calc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Office Spreadsheet (Calc) - Concatenate text cells with delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825886/open-office-spreadsheet-calc-concatenate-text-cells-with-delimiters)

Comment: @tohuwawohu Nice, thank you. Will definitely take a closer look. However, this question differs from the suggested solution inasfar as I want to get rid of the requirement that the values need to be in a connected range

Comment: Ooops - you're right, insofar your question in fact isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=67880, it is possible for a Basic function to use a variable number of arguments if it is declared with `Option Compatible`.  This makes it behave more like MS Excel.  The argument is declared as `ParamArray pa()`.

The link that @tohuwawohu posted shows most of the implementation details needed.

To do it in a way that is more native to LibreOffice, write a Spreadsheet Add-In with a Java declaration that uses `any[]` as an argument.  For information about add-in argument types, see https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/AddIn.html.

The actual function can also be implemented in Java.  Or, it can probably be implemented in another language that accepts a variable number of arguments, such as Python `*args`.